# Visual Studio 2012 Conditional Bundling

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012, bundling-and-minification

I just began working with VS 2012 RC. I've created a test site with a master page and a single web form. Currently, I'm using this code to bundle the entire `Styles` folder on the site:

**Global.asax**

```
BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();
```

**Site.master**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/css" />
```

**Question:** The test site has a site-level CSS file that controls the overall look and feel of the site. In addition to the site-level CSS, each page *could* have their own CSS definitions. Is it possible to include only the `site.css` file in the master page, and then conditionally add .css files to the bundle as each page requires?

I tried this in the code behind of `Default.aspx` but it didn't work:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Styles/Default.css"));
```

Comment: If you are only loading site.css in master and then a page css file, then why are you bundling?

Comment: @TimBJames, I *was* loading the contents of the entire folder. I would like to load just the site-level CSS in the master page and then bundle additional CSS files with it as necessary.

Comment: reading this for the first time. Doesn't this defeat the purpose of bundling? After all, without bundling you would load site.css and page1.css in the first load, then when going to page 2 it would only load page2.css, page3.css for page 3, etc.  Assuming that the page specific CSS files are usually much smaller than the general site one, with bundling you'd be loading a different big file in each page, and without bundling you would load a small file in each page, only improvement would be the very first page where you'd load 1 file instead of 2 (same total size)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion:

Goto `Global.asax`. Ensure the method `Application_Start` contains following line:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Find or create class `BundleConfig` as follows, preferrably in folder `App_Start`:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        ...

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~page1").Include(
             "~/Styles/site.css",
             "~/Styles/page1.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~page2").Include(
             "~/Styles/site.css",
             "~/Styles/page2.css"));

        ...

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~pageN").Include(
             "~/Styles/site.css",
             "~/Styles/pageN.css"));

    }
}
```

Now use corresponding bundle in every appropriate page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/page1" />
```

Or better from code:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Styles/page1")
```

(this is `cshtml`, but `aspx` syntax is for sure very similar).

> Note that you must have a separate bundle per page. You should not modify one and the same bundle on the fly. Bundles have virtual Urls. In your example it is just `css`. These are cached by browsers, so regardless weather you have changed the content of bundle on the fly a browser might think this is the same and do not re-fetch it.

---

If you do not want to take care about adding each and every page manually to the method above. You could automate it. Following code could give you an idea how:

```
public class MyStyleHelper
{
    public static string RenderPageSpecificStyle(string pagePath)
    {
        var pageName = GetPageName(pagePath);
        string bundleName = EnsureBundle(pageName);
        return bundleName;
    }

    public static string GetPageName(string pagePath)
    {
        string pageFileName = pagePath.Substring(pagePath.LastIndexOf('/'));
        string pageNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pageFileName);
        return pageNameWithoutExtension;
    }

    public static string EnsureBundle(string pageName)
    {
        var bundleName = "~/styles/" + pageName;
        var bundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor(bundleName);
        if (bundle == null)
        {
            bundle = new StyleBundle(bundleName).Include(
                "~/styles/site.css",
                "~/styles/" + pageName + ".css");
            BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);
        }
        return bundleName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%: MyStyleHelper.RenderPageSpecificStyle(Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath) %>" />
```

Comment: Am I wrong, or does your automation example assume that this is an MVC application?

Comment: Hi James Hill, yes my first quick draft **was** MVC. It was notepad coded and had some bugs also. Now I rewrote it into plain ASP and tested. It seems to work well. Please see my edits.

Comment: FYI - `ResolveUrl()` should be added to your usage. It wont' work without it.