# ASP.NET's Conditional bundling - real world implementation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have many *levels* of user permissions in my site.

So a *junior* user can NOT do things that a *senior* user  can do. *( there are many levels of users. senior vs junior is just for simplification)*.

In *addition* to a server side validation for who is the user and what he can/t do — I also want *NOT* to provide the *Javascript* function registration *at first place* . (So if a user is a *junior* user , then his JS files should not contain JS functions of a *senior* user.)

Example :

The site has a general `add` javascript function which should appear to *all* users:

```
function add() {
    console.log("Add");
}
```

Junior users has higher privilege so they can ALSO do `subtract` . so their JS files include the `subtract` method:

```
function substract() {
    console.log("substract");
}
```

<sub>*A general users  won't have this `substract` method*</sub>

Senior users has higher privilege so they can ALSO do `power`. so their JS files include the `power` method :

```
function power() {
    console.log("power");
}
```

<sub>*A senior  user won't have this `power` method*</sub>

OK

According to [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658390/859154) :

> Note that you must have a separate bundle per page. You should not
>   modify one and the same bundle on the fly....etc...

So , I created ( for now) 2 bundles  , one for each page :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~page1Junior").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/General.js", "~/Scripts/Junior.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~page1Senior").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/General.js", "~/Scripts/Senior.js"));
```

And then I take the relevant bundle according to some login and use :

```
<script src='@Scripts.Url("~/page1Senior (or) Junior")' async> </script>
```

**Question**

This seems like a wrong way to go.

If I have `10` pages and `10` user levels  , According to that approach  , I will need **100** different bundles.

what is the *right* way of serving appropriate js files for their relevant user permissions ?

Pseudo code of what i'm after :

```
user level       js files(combined to one)
------------|-------------
    1            [a,b]
    2            [a,b,c]
    3            [a,b,c,d]
    4            [a,b,c,d,e]
```

So If a user level 3 is logged on , then a single `abcd.js` JS file should be served ( minified).

Comment: Why would you have one bundle per page? That by itself would probably not be a good thing for performance.

Comment: @usr I didn't say it. I was [referencing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580274/visual-studio-2012-conditional-bundling/11658390#11658390) to an answer which states that claim.I'm Open to New Ideas

Comment: Put the bundles on your layout then you wont need to have it on every view

Comment: @heymega Still , what about the glue between user and the specific JS's files ? can you post an example which will be clear not to me but also for readers ?

Comment: "page1Junior" and "page1Senior"  is just the names of bundles. They are created once on application start and can be used in any number of pages. So if you name your bundle "General+Junior" you can use it in any page. How do you conclude you need 100 bundles?

Comment: @achitaka-san Re-reading your comment , it does make sense. I just need to create a level bundle  ( general+user)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [DynamicBundleFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.dynamicfolderbundle(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you can have a directory structure like

```
Scrtips
-- /Permissions
   -- /1
      -- a.js
      -- b.js
   -- /2
      -- a.js
      -- b.js
      -- c.js
   -- /3
      -- c.js
      -- d.js
```

where 1,2,3 are the restriction levels, then in your `RegisterBundles` add a `DynamicBundle`

```
bundles.Add(new DynamicFolderBundle("userScripts", "*.js",new JsMinify()));
```

And then in your _layout.cshtml, you can do

```
@{
    var userPermissionLevel = 2; // grab your user permission level, from session maybe
}

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Permissions/"+ @userPermissionLevel +"/userScripts")
```

and that will render all the scripts in that directory. You dont have to create bundles for each page then. And if you need to add new permission based file, just add to respective permission folder.

**Update**: This will work fine if you have unique js files for each permission level. For shared files, updating them will be quite a work. So what you can do is create bundle according to permission levels like

```
    // Bundle for permission level 1
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/permissions/1").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/a.js")
                            .Include("b.js"));

    // Bundle for permission level 2
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/permissions/2").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/b.js")
                            .Include("c.js"));

   // and so on for each level 3,4,5 include specific level files
```

and then again you can add them to page throught `_layout.cshtml`

```
@{
   var userPermissionLevel = 2; // grab your user permission level, from session maybe
 }

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/permissions/"+userPermissionLevel)
```

Comment: There's also a great explanation [here](http://www.konstrui.nl/en/about-us/blog/daniel-plomp/2014/04/02/implement-the-microsoft-optimization-framework-into-dynamicweb). it's all about SUFFIXs.

Comment: There is still a problem here because of multiple cloned files ... For example : A.JS should not appear many times

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes you are right. This solution will work best if you have unique js files for each permission level. If you have shared js files, then managing them will be quite a work.

Comment: Thanks for your edit . Regarding the dynamic bundle , I think it's still can be made like you suggested .but first I need to take control over the order of script addition . Would you mind having a look here ?http://stackoverflow.com/q/32474440/859154