# Add additional ordered bundles to a DynamicFolderBundle?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-optimization, asp.net-bundling

I have a `DynamicFoldewrBundle` :

```
bundles.Add(new DynamicFolderBundle("userScripts", "*.js", true, new JsMinify()));
```

So If I run :

> http://optimization.localtest.me/files/templates/designs/HelloTreble/**userScripts**

...It  will render all Javascript files bundled and minified in the `HelloTreble` folder.

OK.

**Question :**

But how can I add *custom ordered* bundles to `DynamicFolderBundle`?

I have tried this :

```
bundles.Add(new DynamicFolderBundle("userScripts", "*.js",new JsMinify())
       .Include("~/Scripts/A.js").Include("~/Scripts/B.js"))
```

Which *does* work.

But the output is  :

- First :  A.JS
- Second : B.js
- Third : [All `HelloTreble`'s js files , minified]

(<sub>In one file of course</sub>)

But what I'm really after is :

- First :  [All `HelloTreble`'s js files , minified]
- Second : A.js
- Third : B.js

(<sub>In one file of course</sub>)

Comment: You can try to implement your own custom `IBundleOrderer` and set it when creating the `DynamicFolderBundle`: `var userScripts = new DynamicFolderBundle("userScripts", "*.js",new JsMinify())
                .Include("~/Scripts/A.js").Include("~/Scripts/B.js");
            userScripts.Orderer = new MyBundlerOrderer();
            bundles.Add(userScripts);`

Comment: @RoyiNamir I just checked with my code, mvc v5.2.3 and my order of scripts is same as what you are looking for. A.js,B.js, then minified scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `IBundleOrderer` interface like

```
public class MyBundleOrderer : IBundleOrderer 
{ 
    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files) 
    { 
        var list = new List<BundleFile>(files); 
        list.Reverse(); 
        return list; 
    } 
}
```

and then attach this to your `DynamicFolderBundle` like

```
var myDynamicBundle = new DynamicFolderBundle("userScripts", "*.js",true,new JsMinify())
.Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/respond.js");

myDynamicBundle.Orderer = new MyBundleOrderer();
bundles.Add(myDynamicBundle);
```

Your scripts will be rendered in order `respond.js`, then `bootstrap.js`, then your scripts in `userScripts` bundle.

Comment: But what if I want my included files in the order I included them, then the dynamic folder bundle?  Reverse only gets me part of the way